# Classifying algebras with two idempotent generators and involution

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, rt.representation-theory, reference-request, coxeter-groups

Say that a finite-dimensional algebra $H$ over a field $K$ is *dihedral* if $H$ is generated by idempotents $P_1$ and $P_2$ and there is an algebra involution interchanging $P_1$ and $P_2$.

For example, the group algebra of a dihedral group is dihedral in this sense. In my paper [Nonstandard braid relations and Chebyshev polynomials](http://arxiv.org/abs/1010.0421), I study a family of dihedral algebras in which $P_1$ and $P_2$ satisfy a fancy version of the braid relation involving Chebyshev polynomials evaluated at $\frac{1}{u + u^{-1}}$, where $K=\mathbb{Q}(u)$.

I am working with a student on generalizing this paper and we have first decided to classify all dihedral algebras. We are willing to assume split semi-simplicity but it would be nice to not require this. We think we can do the classification in the split semi-simple case: all irreducibles are one or two dimensional and there are eight cases depending on which kinds of one-dimensional irreducibles appear.

Since this class of dihedral algebras seems quite natural and the classification has turned out to be more interesting than expected, we are wondering

> Have dihedral algebras been studied and/or classified before?

Of course, many examples of dihedral algebras have been studied, but we are wondering if this entire class of algebras has been studied.